# How to set expiry date in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to set an expiry date of 90 days onto the setCookie I wrote.

```
  function submitDemoToLead(token) {
    redirect();
    Cookies.set('email', $("#sfemail").val());
    Cookies.set('phone', $("#sfphone").val());
    $("#sfDemoForm").submit();  
  }
```

I am a noob and not sure what needs to be done with it.
Could anybody help me understand what should be done?

I am using the CDN below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how

```
 Cookies.set("email", $("#sfemail").val(, { expires: 90 });
 Cookies.set("phone",  $("#sfphone").val(), { expires: 90 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 90 });`

More details: [JavaScript Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)